# Install Python to run speedtest-cli on Android phone with no access to device - via adb

Tags: adb, termux, python

I want to install Python on an Android phone (the phone is connected to a Raspberry Pi so I don't have any GUI or physical access to the device). I can connect to the phone via `adb shell` and run/install packages via APK files easily. I want to install Python on the device to run `speedtest-cli` remotely via `adb shell`. https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli

`speedtest-cli` requires Python. So far I have tried the following based on online articles.

1. Installed Termux app via APK. I can access the underlying files remotely. I tried to install python using `pkg` command but could not. Error below.

   ```
   1|:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin # ./pkg install python                                                                                                                                               
   This must NOT be run as root as it will break your environment (root will be required for nearly everything due to changed file permissions)
   1|marlin:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin # whoami
   root
   ```
2. Installed Qpython on the device using adb. However, the issue is that when I launch adb command to launch Qpython, I see a prompt on the device - "Allow Qpython to access media Options - Accept or Deny". Since I don't have access to the device, I can't select either of the options. Is there a way to send a command via ADB to select - Accept?

I would appreciate any other ideas as well. My end goal is to run the `speedtest-cli` utility via `adb shell` on a device that is not physically accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this eventually. Here is what I did -

1. Installed Termux via downloading the APK and performing `adb install com.termux.apk`
2. Remotely launched the Termux app via ADB (monkey) (this is needed to complete the installation on the device) `monkey -p com.termux -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`
3. Once Termux is installed, I installed `python` and `speedtest-cli` on the device using `adb input text` and `keyevents` -

   ```
   adb input text "pkg install python"
   adb input keyevent "66"
   adb input text "pip install speedtest-cli"
   ```
4. Then navigate to `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin`. Here you should have the `speedtest-cli` script that you can invoke from `adb shell`

   ```
   /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin # ./speedtest-cli                                                                                                                                                      
   Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
   Testing from XXXXX
   Testing download speed................................................................................
   Download: 20.18 Mbit/s
   Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
   Upload: 3.98 Mbit/s
   ```

Comment: I had to add a `COUNT` param to the monkey command, i.e. `monkey -p com.termux -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1`

Comment: And you can alternatively do `am start -n com.termux/.HomeActivity` to open Termux (though you may have to close the soft keyboard, e.g. `input keyevent 4`)

Answer (score 1):

I basically followed the solution given by [rfguy](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/302363/rfguy).
But I had this error:

> could not find a version that satisfies the requirement speedtest-cli
> (from versions: none)
> pip is configured with locations that require tls/ssl

[image]

I solved installing `openssl` too on Termux, as follows:

```
# uninstall Termux
adb uninstall com.termux
sleep 2

# install the apk
adb install -r ~/Desktop/Termux.apk
sleep 2

# open the app
adb shell monkey --pct-syskeys 0 -p com.termux 1
sleep 8

# install python
adb shell input text 'pkg%sinstall%spython'
sleep 2

# enter
adb shell input keyevent 66
sleep 15

# yes
adb shell input text 'Y'
sleep 2

# enter
adb shell input keyevent 66
sleep 60

# install openssl
adb shell input text 'pkg%sinstall%sopenssl'
sleep 2

# enter
adb shell input keyevent 66
sleep 10

# yes
adb shell input text 'Y'
sleep 2

# enter
adb shell input keyevent 66
sleep 15

# install speedtest-cli
adb shell input text 'pip%sinstall%sspeedtest-cli'
sleep 2

# enter
adb shell input keyevent 66
sleep 30

# run speedtest-cli
adb shell /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/speedtest-cli

# hide termux
adb shell pm hide com.termux
```

You can run this script with a `sh .\this_script.sh` if you are already connected to the device with an `adb connect your_device_ip`