# How to run a WiFi speed test periodically and log results?

Tags: wi-fi, internet, logging

I would like an app (or some other method) that will run every N minutes and check the WiFi speed and log the result.

I tried this using Open App Scheduler to run a speed test (from speedtest.net) but this fails because the speed test requires the user to press "Go". Speedtest does keep a history log.

So I need a way to log the result but does not need user input. If it's an app, would it also need to exit the app after each run?

Thank you.

Comment: Those online tests allow you to test your internet connection. Your Wifi speed is usually faster than your internet connection speed. For checking your Wifi speed install an iperf3 server in your local network connected via ethernet to your Wifi router and execute the iperf3 client on your phone. Using termux you should be able o use a script that performs the test periodically.

Comment: Do you really want to check your WiFi speed?  Or do you want to check your Internet speed that is available via your WiFi connection?

Comment: For the internet speed test, there's a Q&A about running Speed Test from CLI: [Install Python to run speedtest-cli on Android phone with no access to device - via adb](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/215442/44325). Perhaps it's possible to write a script and run it periodically.

Comment: @Robert I had to install openssl, too.