# How to install vdirsyncer on Android?

Tags: termux, python

I would like to use [vdirsyncer](https://github.com/pimutils/vdirsyncer) on android. To do so, I first installed [termux](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/) and than ran:

```
apt install python python3
pip3 install vdirsyncer
```

However, that throws the warning:

> Warning pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Then it tries that 4 times, after which it says:

> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/vdirsyncer there was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org, port=443)
> Error: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vdirsyncer (from versions: none)

So it seems to me I should either ensure ssl module is available on Python, or reconfigure pip with locations that do not require TLS/SSL. I have not yet found out how to do that, hence, I would like to ask:

How can one install vdirsyncer on Android?

Comment: [This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/245798/44325) mentioned that `openssl` needs to be installed on Termux.

Comment: Also you should use the [F-Droid Termux](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/) as the one on Google Play is [no longer supported](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/2144)

Comment: Thank you, installing `openssl` indeed resolved the issue. @MorrisonChang thank you, that was the one I used, and I updated the link accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by Andrew T. and in [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215442/install-python-to-run-speedtest-cli-on-android-phone-with-no-access-to-device/245798#245798) answer, a solution was found by installing openssl with: `pkg install openssl`. The full script looks like:

```
pkg install python python3
pkg install openssl
pip3 install vdirsyncer
```

This code can be ran within Termux and installs `vdirsyncer`.